# Where to place ||

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ipod

I know that this is a really simple question, but where should I place the || below if I want to check for both CAF and AAC? Thanks!

```
if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"caf"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"caf"] ||
    [[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"aac"] )
```

Note - this is a literal comparison so it is not case insensitive - if you want to do a case insensitive comparison:

```
if ([[file pathExtension] compare:@"caf" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame || 
    [[file pathExtension] compare:@"aac" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"caf"] || [[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"aac"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to test it twice:

```
if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"caf"] ||
    [[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"aac"])
```

Or, avoid some repetition by doing it like:

```
NSString *ext = [file pathExtension];
if ([ext isEqualToString:@"caf"] ||
    [ext isEqualToString:@"aac"])
```

Comment: This method will also take up slightly less memory :)

Answer (score 0):

`||` means 'or' in Objective c. So this `if (a == 1 || a == 2)` means if a is equal to 1 OR a is equal to 2. So:

==  equal

&& and

||    or